# Dynamic skinning

Tags: php, jquery, css, skinning

I have to change the color skin on the website dynamically according to the color codes supplied from backend on PHP. User is prompted to choose 5 colors at backend. Skins are to be created according to those 5 colors.
I already have working css, but static. Now I need to convert all those colors in static css according the color code being choosen. For example if 1st color among 5 being choosen from backend is green. so the green button on hover must be slightly light.
What will be the good practice for these types of problem? Should I make a formula like finding the difference of light and dark green color codes (so that if user chooses red instead of green, then it will get light red on hover)? Or are there any other ways?

Comment: don't know if its the best approach, but in a similar situation, i created 5 different css files and load the proper one, based on user selection

Comment: No, I need thousands of skins based on any five colors the user choose. for example color 1 can be choosen on thousands of ways, similarly all five colors can be choosen and thousands of thousands of  skins can be generated. 5 css will generate only five skins.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to work with opacities like giving the button a background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
whichs gives the button the background color with 50% black on top of it which makes the button slighty darker.

For passing a chosen color to templates, i make sure all the html elements which colors need to be altered, has one or two generic css classes. Than just print 2 css lines with php which overwrites the default styling.

```
.bg-color {
   background-color:red;
}
.font-color {
   color: red;
}
```